# Button to input text and move to next available column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create 10 buttons each valued 1-10, once that button is clicked I am looking to have this button value input into A2, the following into B2, and so on until F2 (6 scores).

For example, Judge A scores 8, button 8 is clicked and column below Judge A is filled.
Judge B scores 7, button 7 is clicked and following column below Judge B is filled.

I will then Submit this information into another Sheet but I think I have that figured with a separate macro.

I have managed to get buttons to print vertically down but not to fill in the row, I tried:

```
Range("A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

This would keep selecting the row with data and not selecting the next column as I previously expected.

I have looked at the questions people have asked in the past but they seem more advanced than I think I would require for this?

Comment: `.Offset(1, 0)` means "next row" - `.Offset(0, 1)`  means "next column" 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset

Comment: Range("A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select is Application Error and with Range("A:A") always select the A2 cell.

Comment: Are you thinking in a multi-user network spreadsheet?

Comment: This will be a single-user initially but it is likely to be saved to a drive but used locally.

Answer (score 0):

Determining which judge clicked which button is tricky if it's non-consecutive, but the following will print the text of the clicked button to the next available cell.

**EDIT:** Misread question. Code now iterates over columns first, then rows.

```
Sub ButtonClicked()
    Const COL_LIMIT = 6
    
    'Move to next row
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Move to next column
    Dim iLastCol As Long
    iLastCol = Cells(iLastRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    
    'Clicked Button Text
    Dim buttonText As String
    buttonText = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text
    
    'Moves to next row after filling
    If iLastCol > COL_LIMIT Then
        iLastCol = 1
        iLastRow = iLastRow + 1
    End If
    
    'Store at location
    Cells(iLastRow, iLastCol).Value = buttonText
End Sub
```

Comment: The scoring is generally consecutive, I can just manually edit if required if this changes. This code seems to work very well though for the consecutive scoring, thank you for taking the time for this.